# OOP puzzle. Players in clubs and clubs with players

Tags: .net, oop, class, object

I don't know if this is right place. But I need answer very much.

I'm writing program for tournament management. I have simple problem but for me it is not that clear.

There are many clubs (One club from one city). There are players in club. There are no players without club.

I have Player class and Club class.
Should I keep list of players in Club class or keep players club in his class?
Which way would be better?

Comment: Create the references you need. You can link both ways, even both ways at the same time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since every Player has a Club, keep a list of Players in the Club class. This makes it fast and simple to enumerate or search all Players in a given Club. However, there's no reason you can't also have a reference in the Player class which points to its parent Club. There are valid use cases for having a link in each direction, so do both.

I'm assuming that each Player can only belong to one Club. Things will get a bit more complicated if that is not the case.

An example in C#: (not compiled / tested, so it may have some minor errors)

```
public class Club
{
   // other class members

   // this is private so that code must use Club's methods to get at the Players
   private List<Player> _players;

   public int PlayerCount
   {
      get
      {
         return _players == null ? 0 : _players.Count;
      }
   }

   public void AddPlayer(Player p)
   {
      // null checking etc
      // here you could enforce a rule that p.ParentClub must be null
      // to prevent a Player from being in multiple Clubs
      p.ParentClub = this;
      _players.Add(p);
   }

   public void RemovePlayer(Player p)
   {
      // null checking etc
      _players.Remove(p);
      p.ParentClub = null;
   }
}

public class Player
{
   // other class members

   public Club ParentClub 
   { get; set; }
}
```

Now, you can do things like this:

```
// add Player Joe to the London Club if it is not full (10 members max)
// otherwise add Joe to the Munich Club
if(londonClub.PlayerCount <= 10)
{
   londonClub.AddPlayer(joePlayer);
}
else
{
   munichClub.AddPlayer(joePlayer);
}

// print how many players are in the club that Joe is in
Console.WriteLine("Number of Players in Joe's Club: " + joePlayer.ParentClub.PlayerCount.ToString());

// move Joe to the Amsterdam club. Note that it does not matter what Club Joe was already in
joePlayer.ParentClub.RemovePlayer(joePlayer);
amsterdamClub.AddPlayer(joePlayer);
```

Comment: I like that idea. So my properties (setter method) should keep sync of this? For example. When adding player to Club it should automaticly check update Club in players class? While changing club in player class should remove him from all clubs? This creates other problem. I will be forced to send whole Club list to player class.

Comment: You don't really need to sync anything if you utilize oop.  An interface for Players is one solution -- have a setClub() method for a player.  Then you write an addPlayer() method for Club that accepts a member.  It adds the member to its internal array AND it calls member.setClub(this) or whatever the right syntax is for your language.  Apologies in advance although you didn't specify what language you're using, which might be a good addition to your tags.

Comment: @Hooch I have added an example which will hopefully explain better. Please comment if you have more questions and I will expand further.

Answer (score 1):

It depends how you need to use the data.

- If you need to be able to get at all `Player`s in a `Club`, then your `Club` class should maintain a list of `Player`s.
- If you need to be able to get the `Club` that a particular `Player` belongs to, then the `Player` class should maintain a `Club` variable.
- If you need both, then use both but make sure to keep them in sync whenever one changes.

To keep them in sync, you essentially need two different versions of each method.  The first version (the "public" one) automatically handles the side-effects of the call and syncs the two representations.  The second version is what *gets* called by the first version.  It doesn't perform any syncing because that would lead to infinite loops.

This looks something like the following:

- **Club.AddPlayer (Player player, boolean sync=true)**

  1. Add `player` to this club's player list.
  2. If sync:

     1. Call `RemovePlayer(player,false)` on `player`'s current club.
     2. Call `SetClub(this,false)` on `player`.
- **Club.RemovePlayer (Player player, boolean sync=true)**

  1. Remove `player` from this club's player list.
  2. If sync:

     1. Call `player.SetClub(null,false)`.
- **Player.SetClub (Club club, boolean sync=true)**

  1. Set the player's club to `club`.
  2. If sync:

     1. If the player club is not `null`, call `RemovePlayer(this,false)` on it.
     2. If the `club` is not `null`, call AddPlayer(this,false)` on it.

This seems unnecessarily clunky, so I hope someone else has a better idea... :-)

Comment: ".NET" isn't a language, it's a cross-language framework that can be used in *any* of the CLI languages.  See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.NET_Framework and http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Language_Infrastructure

Answer (score 1):

If you use dependency injection, then the answer is, you do both.  In the Club, you have an array structure that holds an array of player oubjects.  In player you have a club variable that stores a Club object.

Comment: How is dependency injection related?

Comment: DI is overkill, this can be solved with the simplest OOP design.

Comment: DI is a class design philosophy which can be used or not.  It is a choice that has no intrinsic overhead.  I can design object relationships to be loosely coupled or not.  In this case I think that design fits the description very well.  The c# example he accepted happens to be a DI implementation.

Answer (score 0):

You can link both ways depending on the purpose. Code up a Club Class with a `list<int> PlayerIds` and a Player class with a `int ClubId` and use either depending on the operation.

eg if your showing a Club page its easier to use the Club class, if your showing a Player page its easier to use the Player class.

Comment: I'm not a microsoft .net guy, but I don't see why these need to be integers.  Doesn't c# have the ability of a variable to store an object?  I'm assuming it does ;D

Comment: @gview this is a programming concept its not exclusive to .Net. My advice is if you use a RDBMS `ints` work well, if you using a no-SQL database then feel free to store objects. Its also a matter of eager loading vs lazy loading, the latter is the one that I default to for performance reasons.

Comment: he clearly tagged his question as being about classes and objects, hence my comment.